# SCSS doesn't compile when function is commented out - CompileSass

Tags: css, visual-studio, sass

Unfortunately I'm having to go back through my CSS and re-write some styling to make sure it works for IE8 (client needs it). I have a function that adds z-index to elements,

```
.mobile-pane {
    ....
    ....

    /* won't work for IE8 */
    /* @for $i from 1 through 4 {
        &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
            z-index: #{$i};
        }
    } */

    &:first-child {
        z-index: 1;

        & + .mobile-pane {
            z-index: 2;

            & + .mobile-pane {
                z-index: 3;

                & + .mobile-pane {
                    z-index: 4;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the function is clearly commented out. However (I'm using [CompileSASS](https://samrueby.com/2015/03/12/visual-studio-extension-to-compile-sass/) for Visual Studio), in the output window, I see this:

```
CompileSass 8:35:55 AM:Sass compilation failed for main. 
Error: C:/projectFolder/source/sass/components/header:219: unbound variable $i
```

In Google WebDev, I'm seeing the function's output, `....:nth-child(2) { z-index:2; }` ... and so on, not

```
.mobile-pane:first-child+.mobile-pane {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

, as I would expect. I'm some-what new to SCSS, so I don't know if this is a known problem, or if [CompileSass](https://samrueby.com/2015/03/12/visual-studio-extension-to-compile-sass/) is not reading the comments correctly.

I understand that I could leave the function in, and just have the IE8 z-index CSS below it, and it will still work, but I wanted to leave the function, in case in the future IE8 was no longer a requirement.

**My question** - is it normal for SCSS to do this, or is it the extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing variables within CSS comments is expected, declaring variables within comments is not.

```
$i: 100;

/* commenting about #{$i} */
```

Output:

```
/* commenting about 100 */
```

Meanwhile:

```
/*
$j: 100;

commenting about #{$j} */
```

Raises an error:

> Undefined variable: "$j".

If you want to comment out blocks of code that access variables that don't exist due to being commented out, use double slashes instead:

```
$j: 100;

.foo {
// content: $j;
}
```

Comment: Good to go, didn't know this. Apprec.